# Making 「たくさん」act as a full-fledged 形容動詞{けいようどうし}

Tags: parts-of-speech

[dic.yahoo.co.jp](http://dic.search.yahoo.co.jp/search?ei=UTF-8&fr=kb&p=%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%95%E3%82%93&dic_id=all&stype=prefix)、[weblio.jp](http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%95%E3%82%93)、and other dictionaries, state that the parts of speech for「たくさん」are noun and 形容動詞。imho, usage cases where たくさん is used as 形容詞 is uncommon. I have seen たくさん take the な particle in sentences such as "写真{しゃしん}がたくさんな記事{きじ}" . But, I have never seen たくさん take the に particle.

I recently heard the sentence:

> "人がたくさん参加{さんか}した。"

That sounds ok to me but looks weird. I cannot help but wonder if something grammatically needs to be between "たくさん" and "参加". Surely, there must be a 助詞{じょし}, Perhaps, can you write:

> 人がたくさん **に** 参加した

To function as a full-fledged 形容動詞、たくさん must be able to take the 「に」助詞. I've never said "...たくさんに...". I would like to add this to my vocabulary. examples please?

In the thread titled [たくさん：形容動詞](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2642823) *Tonky* seems to say that "...たくさんに..." never happens. In the lengthy thread titled [usage of たくさん vs. 多い](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/864/usage-of-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%95%E3%82%93-vs-%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%84?rq=1) no one creates a sentence that has the "...たくさんに..." construct.

If たくさん can take な, but not a に、then it would be questionable whether it is really a 形容動詞, right?

Comment: I think you might find the classifications in most Japanese dictionaries misleading for this particular word.

Comment: So, the 助詞 between "たくさん" and "参加" feels like "が" to me.  But, omitting "が" puzzles me because the meaning of は vs. が seems so important you can't omit either. As omitting an を is standard fair, maybe it is "たくさんを参加した" (but that sounds weird to me). In speaking I'd just say "たくさん参加している" and leave it at that. The 助詞 really doesn't matter I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think there are a couple of points to make here:

1. Nouns of quantity are similar to number+classifier compounds in that they're often used in "bare form" as adverbs:

   > りんごを1個食べた ~ 1個のりんごを食べた
   >   りんごをたくさん食べた ~ たくさんのりんごを食べた

   in both cases, the former version with the adverbial form is the more natural one, and the latter tends to be used only when for some reason, the number+classifier+noun needs to be confined into one noun phrase. Note therefore: **No particle is missing after たくさん**.
2. The reason that *たくさんに doesn't exist is not that たくさん is not a 形容動詞, but semantic reasons, similar to how there's no "manily" in English, and "in a many way" doesn't make sense.
3. It seems you might not be aware that some 形容動詞 take の instead of な, for example たくさん and 普通. You'll find that there's some discussion whether it really makes sense to label these as 形容動詞 (see e.g. [So-called の-adjectives - how does の *really* work?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2770/so-called-%E3%81%AE-adjectives-how-does-%E3%81%AE-really-work)), but at least this explains why you found that label in your dictionary.