# Does 才能にたくさん恵まれている sound correct?

Tags: grammar

I'm trying to say "blessed with many talents", but I am not sure if I am using たくさん　correctly here. I am thinking that 「たくさんの才能に恵まれている」 is more grammatically correct but I can't think why. Maybe because たくさん　is both an adjective and an adverb, and thus whilst 「たくさん飲んだ」(drank a lot) makes sense, 「たくさん恵まれている」(be blessed a lot) doesn't sound so natural.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 才能にたくさん恵まれている is natural. Dictionaries say たくさん is a na-adjective and noun, and often used as an adverb.

たくさんの才能に恵まれている and 才能にたくさん恵まれている are natural, but I think the latter is used more often. For example, I feel 図書館にはたくさん本がある is more common than 図書館にはたくさんの本がある.

Comment: 「沢山恵まれている」 sounds like "very blessed". OP is specifically saying "blessed with many talents", so the emphasis of "many" should be placed on "talents", not "blessed", in my opinion.

Comment: I think 才能にたくさん恵まれている is generally understood as "blessed with many talents". If you want to mean "very blessed with a talent", you can say "ある(その, 一つの)才能にとても恵まれている.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen that exact phrase, but I have seen 「**多くの**才能に恵まれている」, which is basically the same thing, just a different word for "Many". 
See here for a discussion on 「たくさん」vs「多い」:
[Usage of たくさん vs. 多い](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/864/usage-of-%E3%81%9F%E3%81%8F%E3%81%95%E3%82%93-vs-%E5%A4%9A%E3%81%84). They discuss the adverb-adjective issue that you mentioned.

Comment: 多くの才能 sounds like "a lot of (different) talents" to me, while たくさんの才能 sounds more like "a lot of (one) talent". I can't explain why I think that though, might need a native speaker.

Comment: @Mindful Weren't you a native speaker? How you felt is valid. However, this example is not convenient to explain things because "talent" is a vague object to rigidly count and the example sentence is not entirely wrong while the one with 多くの is more natural for the meaning of "many".

Comment: Maybe I should write some examples here. スマホが多い: Smartphones are popular / preferred スマホがたくさんだ: Look at the piles of smartphones! スマホはたくさんだ: I'm fed up with smartphones

Comment: I would appreciate an explanation for the down vote.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Halfway Dillitante. 多くの才能に恵まれている sounds right. You can also say 才能にとても恵まれている or たくさんの才能に恵まれている.

Yes, I know why you used たくさん. It can be used as an adjective.

e.g.)

- お金をたくさんあげた
- 雨がたくさん降った

However, たくさん恵む somehow sounds unnatural. It's grammatically correct. But still strange. I don't know why. Maybe it's a collocation.